# Select difference between a event date for a unique ID using SQL

Tags: sql, count, min, datediff

I have to *count* the amount of events performed by each user per day. To do that I have to join two tables where one table contains the user_id and the date for each event and the other table contains a calendar with every date.

I tried firs for a unique user ID, but the output for the ***delta_day*** is 0 :

```
 with a1 as (SELECT DISTINCT buyer_account_id_fk,
            event_date,
            count(event_date) as qtide,
            min(event_date) as first_event
 FROM ods.ad_contacts
 WHERE buyer_account_id_fk = 14954020
 and year = 2018
 GROUP BY 1,2
 LIMIT 1000),
 a2 as (select distinct buyer_account_id_fk,event_dt, qtide, 
 date_diff('day', first_event,event_dt) AS delta_day
 from a1
 RIGHT JOIN ods.calendar AS cal ON a1.event_date = cal.event_dt
 limit 1000)
 select buyer_account_id_fk, delta_day, qtide
 from a2
 group by 1,2,3


BUYER_ACCOUNT_ID_FK DELTA_DAY   QTIDE
    14,954,020         0         15
    14,954,020         0         8
    14,954,020         0         1
    14,954,020         0         22
    14,954,020         0         5
    14,954,020         0         9
```

I realized that the problem is in determining the ***min(event_date)*** in which for the same user_id the result is the same as the ***event_date***, because of this ***delta_day*** is igual to 0. But I have no idea how to fix this.

Please, help me!!

Table: *ods.ad_contacts*

```
BUYER_ACCOUNT_ID_FK EVENT_DATE
14,954,020            03/01/18
14,954,020            06/01/18
14,954,020            06/01/18
14,954,020            08/01/18
```

Table: *ods.calendar*

```
EVENT_DT
01/01/18
02/01/18
03/01/18
04/01/18
05/01/18
06/01/18
07/01/18
08/01/18
```

I expect as a result something like:

```
buyer_account_id_fk  delta_day  qtide   
  14,954,020           0          1
  14,954,020           3          2
  14,954,020           5          1
```

Comment: Could you please post input table structure, data and what result you expect to see?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: I am using Oracle.

Comment: I fixed the problem doing a `SELECT min(event_date)` before everything. But thanks for the help :).